# Target class [blade.compiler] does not exist. in Lumen can we use balde in lumen provider

Tags: package, laravel-8, lumen

In Lumen can we use Blade in the Lumen provider?

> Target class [blade.compiler] does not exist.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RolesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('role', function ($role) {
            return "<?php if(auth()->check() && 
                auth()->user()->hasRole({$role})) :";
        });

        Blade::directive('endrole', function ($role) {
            return "<?php endif; ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, it's happening because I believe that you forgot to register the `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider` class.

Also, when registering the Provider, make sure to use `$app->configure('view')` in your **bootstrap/app.php** or `$this->app->configure('view')` from your *Service Provider* to configure your view configuration. Because the view service provider doesn't load the configuration itself.

You can check how the view component is loaded in [a Lumen application](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/b2f65f2b10d1d0607542e8e441bc2a0ba6af6996/src/Application.php#L652-L676).

I did like the following

```php
if (!$this->app->bound('view')) {
    // Lumen doesn't load the view config by default
    $this->app->configure('view');
    $this->app->register(ViewServiceProvider::class);
}
```

Or you can do the `loadComponent` thing as lumen does. And it will solve the issue you stated.